Hidden icon kotlin android
im looking for a working method to hide my app from main screen
i think i need somehow delete LAUNCHER category from manifest file, but user must be able to lunch app inside installation dialog. Or i need to programmatically delete icon after installing, but all answers do not work for me. Im looking for solution in kotlin.
here is manifest file of app that can be run from installation dialog, but dont have any LAUNCHER in activities
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="38.50" android:compileSdkVersion="34" android:compileSdkVersionCodename="14" package="com.example.application" platformBuildVersionCode="34" platformBuildVersionName="14">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="26" android:targetSdkVersion="34"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.WRITE_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS"/>
    <permission android:name="com.example.application.DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.application.DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION"/>
    <application android:theme="@style/ScKit_Resource_Obfuscation" android:label="@string/ScKit_Resource_Obfuscation" android:icon="@mipmap/ScKit_Resource_Obfuscation" android:allowBackup="true" android:supportsRtl="true" android:extractNativeLibs="false" android:fullBackupContent="@xml/ScKit_Resource_Obfuscation" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ScKit_Resource_Obfuscation" android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/ScKit_Resource_Obfuscation">
        <receiver android:name="com.example.application.core.alarm.AlarmReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="CLIENT_RESTART"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.example.application.core.telephony.sms.SmsReceiver" android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.example.application.core.telephony.sms.DeliverySmsReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="SMS_DELIVERED"/>
                <action android:name="SMS_SENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.example.application.core.WapPushReceiver" android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:name="com.example.application.core.SmsActivity" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="sms"/>
                <data android:scheme="smsto"/>
                <data android:scheme="mms"/>
                <data android:scheme="mmsto"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.example.application.core.SmsService" android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:scheme="sms"/>
                <data android:scheme="smsto"/>
                <data android:scheme="mms"/>
                <data android:scheme="mmsto"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:label="@string/ScKit_Resource_Obfuscation" android:name="com.example.application.core.push.PushListenerService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <activity android:theme="@style/ScKit_Resource_Obfuscation" android:name="com.example.application.MainActivity" android:exported="true" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CHOOSER"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.INFO"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="com.android.internal.category.PLATLOGO"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED"/>
                <action android:name="com.ui.OnAlarmReceiver.ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER"/>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.COIN"/>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.COIO"/>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.LUCM"/>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.PROX"/>
                <action android:name="ir.cafebazaar.pardakht.InAppBillingService.BIND"/>
                <action android:name="ru.aaaaaaax.installer"/>
                <action android:name="com.nokia.payment.iapenabler.InAppBillingService.BIND"/>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.INST"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider" android:exported="false" android:authorities="com.example.application.androidx-startup">
            <meta-data android:name="androidx.emoji2.text.EmojiCompatInitializer" android:value="androidx.startup"/>
            <meta-data android:name="androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleInitializer" android:value="androidx.startup"/>
            <meta-data android:name="androidx.profileinstaller.ProfileInstallerInitializer" android:value="androidx.startup"/>
        </provider>
        <receiver android:name="androidx.profileinstaller.ProfileInstallReceiver" android:permission="android.permission.DUMP" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:directBootAware="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="androidx.profileinstaller.action.INSTALL_PROFILE"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="androidx.profileinstaller.action.SKIP_FILE"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="androidx.profileinstaller.action.SAVE_PROFILE"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="androidx.profileinstaller.action.BENCHMARK_OPERATION"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
    

